# Android TextView centering

Tags: android, imageview, android-relativelayout

I need your help with one (maybe simple) issue.

I have a header view of an activity and inside is one ImageButton and a TextView.
[image: header]

I would like the text to be centered in its parent (in my case in a RelativeLayout).
TextView is set to be to the rightOf the ImageButton. ImageButton is alignedParentLeft.

Text in the TextView is changing and can be quite long, so I need it to be put away from the ImageButton.

How can I arrange that?

EDIT: 
The layout I'm using:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/header_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dip"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/selector_header_menu"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/header_menu"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dip"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textColor="@color/header_text"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Apply android:paddingLeft to the textview.

Comment: Well, it could help... isn't here anything more universal?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following property to your TextView (assuming you are using XML)

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

It would be much easier to answer your question if you showed us the code you have already written.

Comment: For the textview modify android:layout_width to be wrap_content

Comment: That doesn't help. Now it isn't centered at all.

Comment: Also remove the following property: android:layout_marginLeft="12dip" from TextView?

Comment: Nope, that isn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer might work, if not try giving this in your TextView section of your .XML file

android:layout_gravity="true"

Better answer would be available , if you would post your code here.

Comment: And I believe that android:layout_gravity="true" doesn't exist in Android.

Answer (score -1):

Try below xml property for TextView:

```
    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/header_title"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginLeft="12dip"
       android:layout_marginRight="12dip"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:background="@color/transparent"
       android:maxLines="1"
       android:text="Test"
       android:textColor="@color/header_text"
       android:textSize="25sp" />
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Well, if I remove toRightOf, it works... but if I put longer text in a textview, it will get over the ImageButton.

Comment: Still the same issue.